# How to run code as an instance you just created in GML

Tags: game-maker

Alright, I'm looking how to create an instance, and then run a chunk of code on the instance I just created, and not have that code run on any other duplicate instances.

Noob question, I know. Please help though?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. For example:

```
with instance_create(posx, posy, obj_enemy)
{
    direction = choose(0, 90, 180, 270);
    speed = 4;
}
```

Or you may separate creation and code:

```
var obj = instance_create(posx, posy, obj_enemy);
...
with obj
{
    direction = choose(0, 90, 180, 270);
    speed = 4;
}
```

Comment: This answer is genius! +1 I never considered using this as a method. I always only set variables and just do obj.var = var2; :p